# How to get objectURL of a file passed using FormData in server?

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, cloudinary

I am using NextJs 13 server actions. I am trying to upload image using server action. In client side react we could easily get the url of that image path. But when in server side i get this url `blob:nodedata:dd734025-1064-4488-875d-096ac846e981`. And when I try to upload this url to cloudinary it will give this error :

```
{
  error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'nature.jpg'] {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'open',
    path: 'nature.jpg'
  }
```

When I log the `formData.get('image')` from the server I get this output :

```js
File {
    size: 1506744,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'nature.jpg',
    lastModified: 1695281415285
   }
```

whereas same url would be different on the client side.
I am sending formdata like this from the client:

```js
      <form
        action={uploadToCloudinary}
        className="mt-4 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-center item-center max-w-xl mx-auto"
      >
        <h1 className="text-3xl mb-8">Upload Image to Cloudinary</h1>
        <Image
          src={image ? image : PlaceHolderImage}
          height={100}
          width={100}
          alt="image"
          className="bg-green-100"
        />
        <Input name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Type your name" />
        <Input name="image" type="file" onChange={handleImageChange} />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-neutral-900 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg"
        >
          {pending ? "Loading..." : "Subimt"}
        </button>
      </form>
```

and my action.js looks like this :

```js
export const uploadToCloudinary = (formData: any) => {
  const image = formData.get("image") as File;
  const res = upload.single(image.toString());
  console.log(res);
};
```

I am guessing the image user upload it has full data of it on the client side and server can't get enough of data. Please help me to understand the formdata on client and serverside.

Comment: could you please provide the code on the client side that you have in the function `handleImageChange`?

Comment: @Aleksandar I have edited my post please have a look.

Comment: Actually, I don't see in the post the function `handleImageChange` and the code you have there.

Comment: @Aleksandar Ohh that's just for displaying the image in frontend. 

```js   const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const image = e.target.files[0];
    setImage(image);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(image);
    setImageURL(url);
  };
```
Here you go :)

Comment: Thanks - How does your Multer configuration look on the server-side?